# Web Scraping in Excel like websites in R

Tags: r

I have the following website [1](http://relatorios.aneel.gov.br/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/RelatoriosSAS/RelSAMPClasseConsNivel.xlsx&Source=http%3A%2F%2Frelatorios%2Eaneel%2Egov%2Ebr%2FRelatoriosSAS%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1) which is like an Excel sheet where we can filter some values to obtain a table result below. Apparently, it is not like extracting a HTML standard page. I am trying to extract all the combination results automatically. We have to insert the Year(Ano), Month (Mes), Consumption Class (DescClassConsumo) and Voltage Band(Faixa de Tensão) and extract the table that appears below. I tried to use the following code:

```
rm(list = ls())
#install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)

url <- paste0("http://relatorios.aneel.gov.br/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/RelatoriosSAS/RelSAMPClasseConsNivel.xlsx&Source=http%3A%2F%2Frelatorios%2Eaneel%2Egov%2Ebr%2FRelatoriosSAS%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1")

#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)

#Using CSS selectors to scrap the rankings section
rank_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.cv-nwl')
```

The result of `rank_data_html` is null, but this is the value I want to extract according to SelectorGadget.

Do you have some tips?

Comment: It's a SharePoint site using an "xlviewer" component. You'll have to use RSelenium (and even that won't be really easy)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a function like this:

```
main <- function(url) {
    x <- read_html(url) # URL is accepted and read_html() parses the page contents
    x <- html_table(x) # Page's html table selected
    x <- data.table(x[[1]]) # Converts html table to data.table
    return(x)
}
```

Then select the portion of the data.table that you want!

Comment: did you try that on this site?